# Selenium VBA and Chromedriver after Version 115

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Prior to Version 115 of Chrome, I would download the latest chromedriver to my local's directory and Selenium VBA would work great!
I would download the exe file from this URL
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

However, now my Chrome browser is running v115, that's not possible to download the EXE file anymore as you have to use "Chrome for Testing Availability". The Github for that is here:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

Previously, I would copy the exe file to this directory:
C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic
and everything would work as expected.

I'm unable to find any sample code samples that show how to "Chrome for Testing Availability" files. They seem to need compiling or something!?

Previously, i'd open Chrome with the following code:

WD_Main.Start "chrome", "https://www.google.com"

WD_Main.Get "https://www.google.com/"

Comment: I've just downloaded SeleniumBasic and ChromeDriver v116 and tested successfully. Code that worked before v115 works the same. Can you be more specific about the problem you are having ... are you not able to download ChromeDriver?

Comment: your question is a bit unclear and possibly a duplicate...

Comment: Sorry, i've updated the question. Hopefully this is clearer.
Also I checked before posting and don't think this is duplicated

Answer (score 2):

Successfully tested with ChromeDriver v116. VBA code using this version is the same as for previous versions.

The process (to download both SeleniumBasic and ChromeDrive) is as follows (though note Google frequently updates it's site so this is true today ... might not be true tomorrow):

- Download SeleniumBasic from https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/ … click 'Release Page' under 'Download' then click the SeleniumBasic executable … run it to install. Identify the installation folder (the folder with Selenium32.tlb / Selenium64.tlb in it … on my device it is C:\Users<my_username>\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic).
- Download ChromeDriver … go to https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/ then click the 'the Chrome for Testing availability dashboard' link. Click the 'Stable' / 'Beta' / 'Dev' / 'Canary' link that has the version matching your version of Chrome (ie in Chrome, select the 3 dots then Help, About Google Chrome and look for the Version number) … for 99% of people, this will be 'Stable'. Identify the relevant 'chromedriver' (not 'chrome') link for your device … for Windows users this will be either the win32 or win64 platform depending on the 'bitness' of your device. Copy the link (it is not a clickable hyperlink) and paste it into your browsers address bar then hit enter … the download will start. When it has completed, in the 'Downloads' folder on your device, unzip the .zip file then copy the 'chromedriver.exe' file and paste a copy into the SeleniumBasic installation folder (ie that you identified above).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was downloading the Chrome file for windows but when unzipping there was no chromedriver.exe - you need to choose the file that says
ChromeDriver NOT Chrome under the stable options- chromedriver files are the lower set - After placing the chromedriver.exe in my Selenium folder the code was up and running for Chrome version 116

Answer (score 1):

OK so sorry. Many thanks for all the quick help. It highlighted the issue which was 100% on me..

I'd been downloading the chrome binary instead of the chromedriver.

Thanks for the answers